# legend inside a loop in a subplot in Matplotlib: what is wrong with my code?

Tags: python, matplotlib, legend

I have a plot with 6 different subplots. I iterate through a loop to make each of the subplots and I want to add the legend for each subplot at this time too. So here is an easy example:

```
matrixSol = scipy.random.random((6,6,4))
print matrixSol
mylegend = ['10 Million','15 Million','1 Million','20 Million','25 Million','5 Million']

for k in range(6):
    print k
    xs = matrixSol[k,:,0]
    ys = matrixSol[k,:,1]
    zs = matrixSol[k,:,3]
    plt.subplot(2,3,k+1)
    plt.plot(ys, zs,'o', c=color[k], markersize=10)#marker = styles[k])
    #print mylegend[k]
    plt.legend((mylegend[k]),loc=2)
    plt.xlabel('X')
    plt.ylabel('Y (%)')
plt.show()
```

The problem is that I am getting a legend that picks only the first symbol of each member of the list, please see figure attached.
What is wrong with my code????
it is such a simple thing! thank you very much! any help will be appreciated![image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use:

```
plt.plot(ys, zs,'o', c=color[k], label=mylegend[k], markersize=10)
plt.legend(loc=2)
```

[image]

alternatively, the solution already indicated by Chris Redford also works:

```
plt.legend((mylegend[k],), loc=2)
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure it's treating the code `(mylegend[k])` in the line:

```
plt.legend((mylegend[k]),loc=2)
```

As if the string (e.g. `'10 Million'`) is itself a list (e.g. `['1', '0', ' ', 'M', 'i', 'l', 'l', 'i', 'o', 'n']`).

If you change that line to use `(mylegend[k],)` (comma to specify it is a tuple), it might work right:

```
plt.legend((mylegend[k],),loc=2)
```

Comment: Thanks for testing it and coming back to +1. I +1ed yours as well for its completeness (ie you tested your solution).

Comment: thank you very much Chris, I tried many things but wouldn't have thought of putting a comma there! this works!